# Why is this Animated.View not animating?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to animate the **width** of an `Animated.View`.

Here's the `constructor` of the component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.barWidth = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.barWidthInterpolate = this.barWidth.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 100]
    });
    this.barWidthToValue = 1;
}
```

Here's the `componentDidMount` hook:

```
componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(
        this.barWidth,
        {
            useNativeDriver: true,
            toValue: this.barWidthToValue,
            easing: Easing.in(Easing.ease),
            duration: 2000,
        }
    ).start();
}
```

And here's the `render` method:

```
render() {
    let colorObj = {
        "green": [ "#9CFFD5", "#00CC76" ],
        "blue": [ "#B0D0FF", "#0066FF" ],
        "red": [ "#FF9C9C", "#FF0000" ]
    };

    let borderRadius = 5;

    console.log(this.barWidth._value);

    return (
        <View style={{ width: "100%", height: 30 }}>
            <Animated.View style={{ width: this.barWidthInterpolate, height: "100%" }}>
                { /* Linear gradient from react-native-linear-gradient */ }
                <LinearGradient start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }} colors={colorObj[this.props.color]} style={{ maxWidth: "100%", minWidth: "100%", height: "100%", borderTopRightRadius: borderRadius, borderBottomRightRadius: borderRadius }}/>
            </Animated.View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Instead of animating, the component just skips to the last value.

Please help, I really don't know what to do. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: try to remove LinearGradient and set backgroundColor for Animated.View, maybe it's problem with LinearGradient

Comment: @CuongTranDuc Did that, still the same result.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked perfectly on android

Comment: @CuongTranDuc That's weird and good at the same time. Maybe I should try it on an actual device.

Comment: @CuongTranDuc I tried the code on a real device, still getting the same result. Any suggestions on what else I should try?

Comment: Use your animation value `barWidth` with state. Create value like this : `this.state = { barWidth: new Animated.Value(0) }` and then use it using `this.state.barWidth` instead of `this.barWidth`.

Comment: @KishanBharda Still not working :( Any other suggestions?